# NVIDIA Drivers on Ubuntu VM

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, tensorflow

Im trying to set up Tensorflow on Ubuntu that I install on Virtual Box.
I already install some packages but still doenst seems to work.
The error message that I get all time while I try to run the nvidia-smi command on terminal is:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldnt communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
```

I also try to install drivers for my GPU(GEFORCE GTX 1050 Ti) and I was getting this message:

```
You do not appear to have NVIDIA GPU supported by the 515.76 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.
```

And

```
You appear to be running an X server; Please exit X before installing.
```

So, Am I facing those problems because I run the Ubuntu system on VM? Is there any change I have to make on my options for this box?
Why VM cant recognition my GPU?

I already install everything it needs on my windows 10 profile and I want to do the same on this Virtual Box

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Never heard of this working via Virtual Box.  If you don't want to install Ubuntu on to your hard disk, you can consider using a USB disk -- boot off of that instead?

Comment: Yeah me neither. And I cant find a page that shows how to install it on VM. Still I want to have both operation systems on so thats why I give it a try... But probably Ill install ubuntu on hard disk.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but my gut feeling is that it would work if somehow you could "pre-allocate" resources from the Virtual Box configuration.  For example, for an image, you can choose to give it 4 threads instead of 1; or 8 GB of memory instead of 4 GB.  Otherwise, what would happen if you played a PC game using the Nvidia card while trying to run Tensorflow on the VM?  I haven't used Virtual Box recently, but I don't think that option to "pre-allocate" parts of the GPU card is available (of course, I might be wrong).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Nvidia divers to a VirtualBox machine. It has no direct access to GPU hardware.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Administrator's Guide for Release 6.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html) **experimental** host PCI devices passthrough is available. I don't know how well this works. That means you must have at least 2 GPUs, and in your case the passed through (1060's) isn't available on your host system. Further you must enable IOMMU for passthrough.To sum it up here some requirements:

- Your motherboard has an IOMMU unit.
- Your CPU supports the IOMMU.
- The IOMMU is enabled in the BIOS.
- The VM must run with VT-x/AMD-V and nested paging enabled.
- Your Linux kernel was compiled with IOMMU support, including DMA remapping. See the CONFIG_DMAR kernel compilation option. The PCI stub driver (CONFIG_PCI_STUB) is required as well.
- Your Linux kernel recognizes and uses the IOMMU unit. The intel_iommu=on boot option could be needed. Search for DMAR and PCI-DMA in kernel boot log.

Another non-free solution is **vmware**.

However on linux systems I favorite the free [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) environment for that purposes.
On this git repo you can clone a nice [Nvidia GPGPU Pass-Through with KVM](https://github.com/lateralblast/kvm-nvidia-passthrough)
start up example.